# SelectBox (Clavinska) attach dynamic generated dropdowns

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

How can I attach the generated DropDown elements with SelectBox (Clavinska)?

my example:

```
$(document).on("mouseenter", function() {
$("#countries").selectBox();
}).trigger('mouseenter');
```

this work, but only on mouseenter, I want to atach on "load"!!!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function () {
     $("#countries").selectBox();
})
```